# после ввода слова для подсчитывания меня закидывает в начальную строку терминала :PS D:\Python starter> , что не так?

Tags: python

```
    elif (vvid == 2):
        for letter in text:
            data = sorted(list(set(text.split())))  
        data[letter] = data.get(letter, 0) + 1
        print(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас опять мешанина в коде

```
    for letter in text:
        data = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
```

зачем вы это делаете в цикле?
по другому же код был:

```
    data = dict()  
    for letter in text:
        data[letter] = data.get(letter, 0) + 1
```

Вы опишите нормально полностью задачу, которую вам надо решить
потому что сейчас вы вставляете куски кода, но совершенно неправильно :)

Если вам надо подсчитать кол-во букв у уникальных слов, то надо делать так:

```
words = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
data = dict()
for word in words:
    for letter in word:
        data[letter] = data.get(letter, 0) + 1
```

Comment: ура, получилось, спасибо большое